How do I fix a broken plexiglass table top, cracked in the center where the umbrella was caught in a high wind and fell over?
It’s a rectangular metal frame table that had the tempered glass shatter after a tree hit the out bldg it was in during an ice storm. I had it replaced with plexiglass. This summer a sudden gust of wind came up and sent the umbrella to the side and it cracked the center hole. How do I fix this?

please add a picture

You need a new table top, it really can't be repaired and be serviceable with the stress of the umbrella on it.

if was cast acrylic it can be solvent welded using ether,  if it was extruded acrylic it has probably warped due to internal stresses and and you're out of luck.

You should reinforce the area around the hole

At the risk of having to repair this more times again you will have to repeat the repair that was done with the plexiglass. Alternatively at greater expense you could get a custom cut tempered glass replacement instead. Be prepared for such glass replacement to be greater in cost that what you may have originally paid for the table.
Some alternatives to consider:

Look into a thicker plexiglass.
A thick plastic material such as PVC may be less costly but may require additional support on the underside to prevent flexure and sagging.
Maybe a table top could be fabricated from one of composite type of decking planks. Undoubtedly this will require some design finesse to deal with the greater thickness of the material and the multiple planks being joined together.

